# How to format 19digit number from code for Excel - C#

Tags: c#, excel, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I am using a winforms C# app to create a CSV file with product IMEI, ICCID and serial numbers. The data is found in an AccessDB and displayed in dataGridView before being all saved in a CSV. However each ICCID number is 19 digits long and when I open the CSV in excel the last few digits have been replaced with 0's.

I know this is due to excel cells only handling up to 15digits and I can fix the problem by going into excel and formatting the column however I don't want to have to open each CSV to fix the column.

Is there a way to do this before I save the CVS in the code?

Edit: The code I am using is from [Here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/export-datagridview-data-to-csv-in-c-sharp)

**UPDATE:** I have tried to add `'` before the number as suggested however when I open the file in excel it still converts the last 4/5 digits to 0.

I also looked into saving the file as an `ms-dos` using `File.WriteAllLines(sfd.FileName, outputCsv, Encoding.UTF32);` but this was also unsuccessful.

Desperate for help :)

```
private void saveShipping()
    {
        if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
            sfd.Filter = "CSV (*.csv)|*.csv";
            sfd.FileName = "shippingOutput.csv";
            bool fileError = false;
            if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                if (File.Exists(sfd.FileName)) 
                {
                    try
                    {//overwrite file
                        File.Delete(sfd.FileName);
                    }
                    catch (IOException ex)
                    {
                        fileError = true;
                        MessageBox.Show("It wasn't possible to write the data to the disk." + ex.Message);
                    }
                }
                if (!fileError)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        int columnCount = dataGridView1.Columns.Count;
                        string columnNames = "";
                        string[] outputCsv = new string[dataGridView1.Rows.Count + 1];
                        for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++)
                        {
                            columnNames += dataGridView1.Columns[i].HeaderText.ToString() + ",";
                        }
                        outputCsv[0] += columnNames;

                        for (int r = 1; r < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; r++)
                        {
                            for (int c = 0; c < columnCount; c++)
                            {
                                outputCsv[r] += dataGridView1.Rows[r - 1].Cells[c].Value.ToString() + ",";
                            }
                        }
                        
                        for (int currentRow = 0; currentRow < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; currentRow++)
                        {
                            string formatICCID = dataGridView1.Rows[currentRow].Cells["ICCID"].Value.ToString();
                            dataGridView1.Rows[currentRow].Cells["ICCID"].Value = "'" + formatICCID;
                        }

                        File.WriteAllLines(sfd.FileName, outputCsv, Encoding.UTF8);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Error :" + ex.Message);
                    }

                    m_shippingPath = sfd.FileName;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No Record To Export", "Info");
        }
    }
```

Comment: They are strings, not numbers, so be sure to put "double quotes" around them.

Comment: What @HansPassant said, or try prefixing with `'` (single quote), like `'123456789123456789`.

Comment: Will the `"` or `'` show up in the csv though?

Comment: Do not **Open** the file in Excel.  Rather **Import** the file using either the legacy wizard or the new data tool.  Then designate that column as being Text.

Comment: Can you share the code you are using?

Comment: Added code to op

Comment: Unfortunately, Excel is a lousy CSV editor. We had the same problem and solved it by prefixing the column content with text, i.e., instead of outputting `123456789`, we'd output `ICCID 123456789`. It's not very elegant, but we did not find a better way to "force" Excel to treat this column as text.